# How to make rendered product variations show in a grid rather than a list?

Tags: commerce

I need to present some product variations rendered in a grid, without any cart options. 
The idea is to have the user click a link to the product and present a page with the variations.

The easiest way I manage to do this is: in content->manage display I only show the field:Product Variations, with the format:Rendered Product, which gives me exactly what I want. Except it is displaying the rendered variations in a vertical list rather than the nice grid like it shows by default in the product list view.

Where does the presentation of this rendered product variation elements come from?

I'm using the default theme:commerce kickstart omega.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily create a View display to list your products in a grid.

1. Add a new View ( Admin > Structure > Views )
2. Add a page display
3. Add relevant filters for entity type etc..
4. Set the style to "Grid" layout
5. Tinker from there with fields etc..

That should do it.